# More theading confusion. Why are Semaphores SO slow?

Tags: python, multithreading, performance, semaphore

This question is a sequel to my previous question ([Threading in Python - What am I missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29631258/threading-in-python-what-am-i-missing)).

Thanks to the people who indicated where the threading problem was. That problem finally solved, I enabled the semaphores and was surprised that just enabling them took the execution time of the program from a fraction of a second to 4 seconds! WOW... 3 seconds for just 80000 iterations seems frighteningly slow, even taking into account the collisions.

The exact times:

```
Without semaphore      0.0167980194092 s
With semaphore         2.76963996887 s
```

Here's the code:

```
import threading
import time
import random

turnstile_names = ["N", "E", "S", "W"]
count = 0
sem = threading.Semaphore(1)

class Incrementer(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, id):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.id = id

    def run(self):
        global count, sem
        for i in range(20000):
            sem.acquire()
            count = count + 1
            sem.release()

def main():

    random.seed(507129)
    incrementers = [Incrementer(name) for name in turnstile_names]

    for incrementer in incrementers:
        incrementer.start()

    # We're running!

    for incrementer in incrementers:
        incrementer.join()

    print count
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Did get `80000` as `count`, *always*, without `Semaphore`?

Comment: "even taking into account the collisions" - collisions is an understatement, this is sequential execution (with the added overhead).

Comment: 80,000 locks in 3 seconds. That's 0.4 ms / lock. Not that bad for threads that do real work, but yes, thread synchronization is not free. You can completely avoid this by having thread local counters and totalling those at the end.

Comment: I have timed your code on my 2700K @ 4.6 GHz using Python 3.4.2. I get .27 seconds per run.

However, that is not your problem. GIL makes sure only one of your threads runs at any one time. It is moot to create threads that do heavy CPU processing in Python.
Threads are only useful if you have I/O bound workload.

Comment: @Thilo: Thanks for the reply.. 0.4ms is an eternity on a 3GHz processor. I just did this example as it is a classic semaphore demo - the incrementing of a common counter was the point.

Comment: @velis: I'll check with Python 3.4.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment on why the semaphore is so slow, but there is a way to significantly speed up your code by using a lock instead of a semaphore:

```
lock = threading.Lock()

class Incrementer(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, id):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.id = id

    def run(self):
        global count, lock
        for i in range(20000):
            with lock:
                count = count + 1
```

No synchronisation: 0.02s
Semaphore synchronisation: 2.69s
Using a lock: 0.36s

That said, I think that acquiring and releasing a semaphore eighty thousand times in slightly more than two and a half seconds is decent performance - thread synchronisation comes at a cost - but you should look at your options and select the tool that fits your use case the best, and in this case it's a lock and not a semaphore since you only have one resource.

Comment: I'm still looking for an explanation for the time spent in the semaphore. If Locks are that much better, why not implement semaphores with locks? Mind: I'm only doing this from an academic point of view - given that semaphores are the 'classic' solution. There are many alternatives. Also, given the apparent difference in performance it might be interesting to mention (or compare) performance in the Python docs.

Answer (score 0):

Semaphores are implemented in Operating System. They offer the ability to synchronize among other processes which can not be achieved using locks.
So the reason that they are slow should be obvious now, each time you interact with a semaphore the process needs to make a system call to OS , context switches to Kernel Mode , do the logic and then again context switch back to the calling process if it is not blocked.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken `threading.Semaphores` have nothing to do with OS semaphores (except similarity). They are implemented inside Python's threading module. This is also evidenced by the fact that OS semaphores need definition of world, group and user privileges. (See C's IPC library)

Comment: @jcoppens Do you have any reference for it ?

Comment: Not immediately. But the fact that `threading.Semaphores` is part of the `threading` library is a very strong indicator. There's a library http://semanchuk.com/philip/sysv_ipc/ for using real, inter-process semaphores in Python, which can interact with other, eg. C semaphores. If I can find some time after the exams today, I'll look into it some more.